# How can I call a method when session is dropped in .NET CORE 6 application?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, session, .net-core

I have a table in the database where I store the user's session key, account ID and date. When the user logged in I insert it into this table and when logged out I delete it. But if a user is not logged out and his session is dropped. Data still remain. So I want to delete his data when the session is dropped. Is there any event that activates when the session is dropped?

I try to add the `OnSessionDropped` function in the options at services.AddSession but .net core 6 is not supporting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .NET Core 6, there is no built-in event that is triggered when a session is dropped.

you can implement a background task which will regularly check the database for stale session records (records that have not been updated in a certain amount of time) and delete them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I check the state sessions?